# Derivative wrt constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, calculus

What is $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V} \right)_V $ ?
Mathematically its undefined but how to understand it for thermodynamic system like ideal gas?
Or in other words,  is $\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial P} \right)_V $ identically zero ?

Answer (score 2):

The quantity
$$\left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial V} \right)_V$$
means the change in pressure with respect to volume when I'm keeping volume fixed. That's quantity has no meaning because you can't change something at the same time keeping it fix.
That's totally opposite things.

Comment: But don't we use quantities like $$\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_P$$ in processes where temperature is assumed constant already.

Comment: Can you put your reference where you have learned this?

Comment: In thermodynamics book by Zemansky. In chapter on thermodynamics potentials.

Comment: Can you put the paragraph and the exact expression?

Comment: Alright. See section on TdS Equations. After deriving second TdS Equation he shows how to calculate heat supplied when pressure is changed isothermaly.

Comment: I don't have the book. But this point may be your doubt.See you can use the expression whenever you need but  you can not measue the quantity with keeping the temperature fixed. You need to choose a isobaric process to know what's the value for this quantity is?

Comment: But this is well defined constant $\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_P *(1/V) =\beta$. Ofcourse we have to calculate it in an isobaric situation but we use it in processes where temperature is constant.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying If you want a measure the value of $\beta$ you need to make an isobaric process. But you can use it in other places. By the way, In your problem, you are talking about $\partial P /\partial V$ at constant $V$ which you can not even measure. So it just not exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity
$$\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right)_x$$
means means the partial derivative of z with respect to y with x held constant. For example, the specific heat at constant pressure is defined as  $$\left( \frac{\partial h}{\partial T} \right)_P$$ and the specific heat at constant volume is defined as $$\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \right)_v$$ where h and u are specific enthalpy and internal energy, respectively, v is specific volume, T is temperature, and P is pressure. Studying thermodynamics will require you to acquire proficiency in understanding applications of the calculus.  For example, the use of an inexact differential for work to indicate the work is path dependent.